# Return the number of nodes in Fibonacci Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree, fibonacci

I want to write a function that returns the number of nodes in the Fibonacci recursion tree, knowing that the number of nodes equals the number of additions required to compute the n-th Fibonacci number - 1.

I have a program that returns the number of additions to compute the n-th Fibonacci number:

```
def main():
    print('(Fn, additions)')
    for i in range(0, 11):
        print(f"F({i}) = {fibR(i)}")

def fibR(n):
    #Base case
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        add = 0
        return (n, add)

    return (fibR(n-1)[0] + fibR(n - 2)[0], fibR(n-1)[1] + fibR(n - 2)[1] + 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can i modify it to return the number of nodes? I tried to change the second component of the return tuple to:

```
return (fibR(n-1)[0] + fibR(n - 2)[0], (fibR(n-1)[1] + fibR(n - 2)[1] + 1) - 1)
```

but it does not work. Can someone help? Thanks in advance

Edit:

Expected Output:

```
(Fn, additions)
F(0) = (0, 0)
F(1) = (1, 0)
F(2) = (1, 0)
F(3) = (2, 1)
F(4) = (3, 3)
F(5) = (5, 6)
F(6) = (8, 11)
F(7) = (13, 19)
F(8) = (21, 32)
F(9) = (34, 53)
F(10) = (55, 87)
```

Comment: Knots? What? Do you mean nodes?

Comment: yes, sorry, edited it

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the more efficient method where you avoid calculating the same Fibonacci number over and over again? Do you consider two nodes distinct when they are about the same Fibonacci number, but recalculated again? Please provide expected output for a few examples.

Comment: I am just learning recursion. Yes, i could memorize the values and etc, but thats not the point

Comment: *"but it does not work."*: looks to work fine. What is the problem you see? Maybe the confusion comes from the recalculation (and recounting) I referred to.

Comment: in the terminal the number of nodes keeps returning zero

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. See it run on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomq774657285459839#main.py). Output is `(Fn, additions)
F(0) = (0, 0)
F(1) = (1, 0)
F(2) = (1, 1)
F(3) = (2, 2)
F(4) = (3, 4)
F(5) = (5, 7)
F(6) = (8, 12)
F(7) = (13, 20)
F(8) = (21, 33)
F(9) = (34, 54)
F(10) = (55, 88)`

Comment: This is returning the number of additions. If you change the return statement like i wrote in the question, then it does not work

Comment: OK, so how do you define a node. Is it a call to `fibR`? Do duplicate calls count as duplicate nodes?

Comment: Like I asked above, could you edit your question and add examples of expected output?

Comment: @trincot Of course, just edited

Comment: I think you slipped up when posting those outputs. it makes no sense that f(2) has 0 additions and so on. Anyways check my answer below for your solution.

Comment: Can you explain what a node is? Why f(0), f(1) and f(2) do not count any "node"? What is it that you want to get counted here?

Answer (score 0):

Your forumla `fibR(n - 1)[1] + fibR(n - 2)[1] + 1` to calculate the number of nodes is correct. But youve a small mistake in your firb() function. You sometimes returned the wrong value for add. See the code below:

```
def main():
    print('(Fn, additions)')
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print(f"F({i}) = {fibR(i)[0],fibR(i)[1]}")

def fibR(n):
    #Base case
    global adders
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        add = n
        return n, add

    return (fibR(n - 1)[0] + fibR(n - 2)[0], fibR(n - 1)[1] + fibR(n - 2)[1] + 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

#output F(n)=(Fibu value, Number of knots)
F(1) = (1, 1)
F(2) = (1, 2)
F(3) = (2, 4)
F(4) = (3, 7)
F(5) = (5, 12)
F(6) = (8, 20)
F(7) = (13, 33)
F(8) = (21, 54)
F(9) = (34, 88)
F(10) = (55, 143)
```

Note that the `number_of_nodes-1=number_of_additions` since the number of additions is the number of branches between the nodes.
Since youve given confusing expected outputs heres a picture where you can verify my results by counting the number of nodes or the number of branches yourself.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but i want to use the number of additions to return the number of nodes, no other fact

Comment: Ok i understand. Ive changed my answer. Please check again

Comment: The formula fibR(n - 1)[1] + fibR(n - 2)[1] + 1 is to calculate the number of additions, not nodes. Also, you changed the main function to subtract 1 and then obtain the number of nodes, but i want that to be done inside the recursive function, that is the point of the exercise

Comment: Ok sorry. i hope my input already brought you a little closer but i dont think i entirely understand your exercise. Maybe upload the exercise? Anyways if you find a solution plz let me know